# Moving Class Out of Appilication Solution to Static Lib Solution Creates Unresolved External Symbol Link Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio 10 set to use the v90 platform toolset. I have three applications that use several of the same classes. So, rather than have three copies of each of those classes, I am trying to move them out into a common static lib. One of them is giving me link problems. The others seem to link fine. Here's the problem class:

HEADER

```
#ifndef LIMIT_SINGLE_INSTANCE_INCLUDED
#define LIMIT_SINGLE_INSTANCE_INCLUDED

#include <windows.h> 

class CLimitSingleInstance
{
protected:
  DWORD  m_dwLastError;
  HANDLE m_hMutex;

public:
  CLimitSingleInstance(TCHAR *strMutexName);
  ~CLimitSingleInstance();
  BOOL IsAnotherInstanceRunning();
};
#endif
```

BODY

```
#include "LimitSingleInstance.h"

CLimitSingleInstance::CLimitSingleInstance(TCHAR *strMutexName)
{
  //Make sure that you use a name that is unique for this application otherwise
  //two apps may think they are the same if they are using same name for
  //3rd parm to CreateMutex
  m_hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, strMutexName); //do early
  m_dwLastError = GetLastError(); //save for use later
}

CLimitSingleInstance::~CLimitSingleInstance() 
{
  if (m_hMutex)  //Do not forget to close handles.
  {
     CloseHandle(m_hMutex); //Do as late as possible.
     m_hMutex = NULL; //Good habit to be in.
  }
}

BOOL CLimitSingleInstance::IsAnotherInstanceRunning() 
{
  return (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS == m_dwLastError);
}
```

When this class is directly part of one of my main application solutions, there is no problem. I have now moved it into my static lib solution, and that solution builds fine. However, I find that I can no longer link my main application solution against my new static lib. Here is the result of attempting to build both debug and release versions of my main application:

> ------ Rebuild All started: Project: WCCJ, Configuration: ReleaseTENA Win32 ------   CAssetEntity.cpp   main.cpp   ReadWCCJParameters.cpp
>   WCCJ.cpp   WCCJParameters.cpp   Generating Code...
>   DCTUtilsRel.lib(MessageWrapper.obj) : MSIL .netmodule or module
>   compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the
>   link command line to improve linker performance
>        Creating library ....\bin\WCCJ-TENA.lib and object ....\bin\WCCJ-TENA.exp main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external
>   symbol "public: __thiscall
>   CLimitSingleInstance::CLimitSingleInstance(char *)"
>   (??0CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@PAD@Z) ....\bin\WCCJ-TENA.exe : fatal
>   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>   ------ Rebuild All started: Project: WCCJ, Configuration: DebugTENA Win32 ------   CAssetEntity.cpp   main.cpp   ReadWCCJParameters.cpp
>   WCCJ.cpp   WCCJParameters.cpp   Generating Code... CAssetEntity.obj :
>   warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/INCREMENTAL:NO'
>   specification
>        Creating library ....\bin\WCCJ-TENA-d.lib and object ....\bin\WCCJ-TENA-d.exp main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   CLimitSingleInstance::CLimitSingleInstance(char *)"
>   (??0CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@PAD@Z) referenced in function "void
>   _*cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'gSingleInstanceObj''(void)" (??*_EgSingleInstanceObj@@YAXXZ) ....\bin\WCCJ-TENA-d.exe : fatal
>   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 skipped ==========

When I open the .lib in a binary editor and search for the mangled name the linker wants (??0CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@PAD@Z), I find that it is indeed not found. The closest matches I can find are:

??0CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@PA_W@Z

??1CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@XZ

@CLimitSingleInstance@@QAEHXZ

Is anybody able to tell me why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The closest matches I can find are: ??0CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@PA_W@Z

Use the undname.exe utility from the VS command line on that symbol:

```
C:\>undname ??0CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@PA_W@Z
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "??0CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@PA_W@Z"
is :- "public: __thiscall CLimitSingleInstance::CLimitSingleInstance(wchar_t *)"
```

Note the argument type, wchar_t*, not char*.  Your lib project has UNICODE #defined, your exe project does not.  The relevant setting is General + Character Set.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is no CLimitSingleInstance::CLimitSingleInstance(char_t *). in your library. Have you checked your defines for both projects?

There is Microsoft utility: `undname.exe` which is part of VisualStudio:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\COMMON\Tools>UNDNAME.EXE
Microsoft(R) Windows NT(R) Operating System
UNDNAME Version 5.00.1768.1Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-1998

usage: UNDNAME [-f] decorated-names...
       -f Undecorate fully.  Default is to only undecorate the class::member
```

**So the linker wants**:

```
>UNDNAME.EXE -f ??0CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@PAD@Z
Microsoft(R) Windows NT(R) Operating System
UNDNAME Version 5.00.1768.1Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-1998

>> ??0CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@PAD@Z == public: __thiscall CLimitSingleInstance::CLimitSingleInstance(char *)
```

**and you have in the library:**

```
>UNDNAME.EXE -f ??0CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@PA_W@Z
Microsoft(R) Windows NT(R) Operating System
UNDNAME Version 5.00.1768.1Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-1998

>> ??0CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@PA_W@Z == public: __thiscall CLimitSingleInstance::CLimitSingleInstance(wchar_t *)


>UNDNAME.EXE -f ??1CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@XZ
Microsoft(R) Windows NT(R) Operating System
UNDNAME Version 5.00.1768.1Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-1998

>> ??1CLimitSingleInstance@@QAE@XZ == public: __thiscall CLimitSingleInstance::~CLimitSingleInstance(void)
```